# Bitwise enumeration in Javascript given an integer

Tags: javascript

I have an object that is uses bitwise enumeration. I also have an integer that corresponds to this object. The object may look like so:

```
let int = 14; // key3 + key4 + key5
let enum {
   key1: 0,
   key2: 1,
   key3: 2,
   key4: 4,
   key5: 8,
   key6: 16,
   key7: 32,
   key8: 64
   // .....
}
// Output: ['key3', 'key4', 'key5'] or something along the lines of this
```

Because 8 + 4 + 2 = 14, I want to write a function which should return key3, key4, and key5. Is this possible in Javascript? And if so, how is it done? If it's not, how can it be done?

Comment: yes, it is possible, and yes, you should add what you have tried, at least add how you would do it with pen and paper.

Comment: You will need to know `8`, `4` and `2` beforehand. how do you get those numbers form `14`?

Comment: it would make more sense if your keys and values were the other way around

Comment: btw, `int` and `enum` are reserved identifiers for upcoming version of js.

Comment: Solution sketch: Repeatedly apply the modulo operator (`% 2`) to generate a 'bit stream' and fill array elements corresponding to the set bits with the canonical power of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you are trying to do something like this:

```js
let enumLike = Object.freeze({
   key1: 0, key2: 1, key3: 2, key4: 4, key5: 8, key6: 16, key7: 32, key8: 64
})

let myInt = 14;

function enumerator(integer) {
  let output = [];
  while (integer > 0) {
    Object.keys(enumLike).reverse().forEach(k => {
      if (enumLike[k] <= integer) {
        integer -= enumLike[k];
        output.push(k);
      }
    })
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(enumerator(myInt));
```

Better approach:

```js
function bitwiseEnumerator(input) {
  return input.toString(2).split('').reverse().reduce((a, current, index) => {
    if (current != 0 ) a.push('key' + index);
    return a;
  }, []);
}

console.log(bitwiseEnumerator(15));
console.log(bitwiseEnumerator(14));
console.log(bitwiseEnumerator(12));
console.log(bitwiseEnumerator(16));
```

NOTE: `key0`= 1, `key1`= 2, `key2`= 4, `key3`= 8, `key4`= 16 and so on. (In this example)

Comment: I was trying to do something like this, yeah. I thought this couldn't be done in Javascript but in my case, it looks like it was possible.

Comment: i think your 2nd approach will only work for keys that are named "key1", "key2", etc... correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @ethanc there's also `key0` whose value is 1. It will be there for all odd numbers. And I'm generating `key` name dynamically using the `index` value from inside `reduce` (See the code)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a bitwise operations and shift one to left until this value is greater than the given value.

Instead of using an object, you could just generate the keys.

```js
var value = 14,
    i = 0;

while (1 << i < value) {
    if (value & 1 << i) {
        console.log(i, 1 << i, 'key' + (i + 1));
    }
    i++;
}
```